# People Picker AllowEmpty Property

Tags: sharepoint, validation, moss, peoplepicker

I am using the people picker user control of SharePoint in my aspx page. I have set the AllowEmpty property of people picker control as false.

But, still the required field validation is not occurring for the control. I don't want to use a required field validation control explicitly for validating this. Any insights?

Regards,
Raghuraman.V

Answer (score 1):

In order to enable/disable [validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.ivalidator.aspx) for [Entity Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.entityeditor.aspx) based controls (like [People Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.peopleeditor.aspx)) the following properties should be specified in combination:

- [AllowEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.entityeditor.allowempty.aspx) - represents whether an empty entity is allowed
- [ValidatorEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.entityeditor.validatorenabled.aspx) - represents whether a Validator is enabled

So, in your case to disable empty values, `ValidatorEnabled="true"` should be provided also like shown below:

```
<wssawc:PeopleEditor
                                      AllowEmpty="false"
                                      ValidatorEnabled="true"
                                      id="userPicker"
                                      runat="server"
                                      SelectionSet="User,SecGroup"
                                      />
```